# What is the max number (if any) of subscriptions a Windows Azure Service Bus Topic can have?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I'm considering an architecture that could have tons of subscribers to a single topic. Like tens or hundereds of thousands of individual subscribers. Each would have a SQL filter, something like:

```
User = 'SomeUserIdentifier'
```

Just wondering if I'm going to run into a max number of subscriptions on a topic at some point.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Service Bus supports up to 2,000 subscriptions per topic.* ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements))

But if you need to go beyond the 2,000 subscriptions limit you can create multiple levels of subscriptions with the [Auto-forwarding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding) capabilities of a Subscription. This means you could have the following:

Topic A

- Subscription 1 -> Auto-forward -> Topic A1 -> Subscription A1.1, Subscription A1.2, ...
- Subscription 2 -> Auto-forward -> Topic A2 -> Subscription A2.1, Subscription A2.2, ...
- ...
- Subscription 2000 -> Auto-forward -> Topic A2000 -> Subscription A2000.1, Subscription A2000.2, ...

This means you would have virtually no limit on the number of subscriptions you could have on a topic.

Comment: Great info thanks. I wonder if better solution would be to simply create a separate unique queue for each user? This raises a similar question, is there a max number of queues a service bus service can support?

Comment: Looks like the number of queues on Azure service bus is unlimited. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh767287.aspx

Comment: Service Bus is limited to 10,000 queues per namespace. The number of Storage Queues is unlimited.

Comment: More specifically, Azure service bus is limited to 10,000 unpartitioned entities (topics and queues) per namespace. Only 100 of those may be partitioned entities. Thus, much more limited when using partitioning.